# Given a matrix $A$, how to find matrix $B$ such that $B^T B=A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Is it possible to find matrix $B$ if we knew matrix $A$ and $B^T B=A$?

For example: $A$ is a symmetric matrix and 
$$
A =  
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2&  3 \\ 
2 & 1 & 4 \\ 
3 & 4 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}?
$$

Comment: This can only be done if the matrix is symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: @MattSamuel why positive definite necessary?

Comment: @MANMAID It could also be positive semidefinite, but it is obvious that (for real $B$) the matrix $B^T B$ must be positive semidefinite.

Comment: @ErickWong yes and thanks, I always get confused in Linear Algebra, that is why I asked... I knew that positive semidefinite, but since Matt used only positive definite, I asked...

Comment: @MANMAID I agree that it was a good idea to ask for the clarification.  Even better if you specified that the uncertainty was regarding the "definite" and not the "positive".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Cholesky decomposition.

Note that there are more than one such $B$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you Math Lover. Is it possible to find matrix B if size of matrix A is nxn, but matrix B is mxn? For example: size of matrix A is 8x8, and matrix B is 3x8.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to find the matrix $B$, as long as $A$ is a positive definite matrix (which are also always symmetric). In this case, $A$ is diagonalizable such that $A=PDP^T$, where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix (i.e., $P^T = P^{-1}$, or $P^T P = I$) and $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose entries are the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$.

Since $A$ is positive definite, these eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are positive. Thus, we can define a diagonal matrix $C$ whose entries are $\sqrt{\lambda_i}$, such that $D=CC$. Utilizing this trick, we can find $B$ as follows:

$A = PDP^T = PCC P^T = PCP^T P CP^T = (P^T)^TC^TP^TP C P^T = (PCP^T)^T(PCP^T) = B^TB $,

such that we find $B = P C P^T$.

Remark: In the second to last step, we utilized the fact that $(ABC)^T = C^T B^T A^T$.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is indefinite,; you need a diagonal matrix in the middle that matches the counts according to Sylvester's Law of Inertia. I don't think all integers is possible.
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
4 & 3 & 0 \\
5 & 4 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
- \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & - \frac{5}{2}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
4 & 5 & 0 \\
3 & 4 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$